# U.S. federal government data fetchable via SPARQL?

Tags: usa, government, linked-data, sparql

I am interested in U.S. federal government information (e.g., agencies/sub-agencies, programs, etc) that I can fetch via the Semantic Web/SPARQL. I am able to get this information via Dbpedia. The information is there but the quality is inconsistent. Is anybody aware of other sources of this type of information that can be accessed via SPARQL or similar technology?

Answer (score 2):

your best bet is to search specific data sites that you want to get the data from...i went to healthdata.gov and found this guy:
http://healthdata.gov/cqld
although their query point throws a 404
OKFN also runs a sparql service to show available endpoints, though you'll have to pick through to find us ones:
http://sparqles.okfn.org/availability

this slideshare set tells you how to do healthcare.gov's data:
http://www.slideshare.net/george.thomas.name/clinical-quality-linked-data-on-healthdatagov

Comment: thank you for the information. for agency information, I will also study the information mentioned in a related post: http://www.usa.gov/About/developer-resources/federal-agency-directory/index.shtml. I suppose it is not realistic to only rely on semantic web information.

Answer (score -1):

CKAN the software behind data.gov has a extension for it, multiple agencies use CKAN to harvest existing services as over 60 extensions exist for CKAN and can harvest other CKAN makes the collection process easy at one level...

Comment: Could you please detail why CKAN is relevant for SPARQL?

Comment: Data.gov the Federal Government's data portal runs on CKAN

Comment: Have you read the question? What the asker wants is a list of SPARQL endpoint URLs.

Comment: Yes I read the question the asker is interested in data from the Federal Government accessible as SPARQL... I figured pointing out the largest data repository for the federal government searchable by topic or open string in tandem to pointing to the extension on github might show which projects had forked/implemented it so they could investigate which SPARQL services are being harvested by CKAN, in other words find some URL end points